Make asterisk ambiguous in a template
There is, IIRC, a way to write a template in which the same occurrence of an asterisk means multiplication in one instance and pointer type (likely in a variable declaration) in another. How do I know? I read it some time ago in an answer on SO! But search tools have failed to lead me back there (or perhaps it was deleted).
Can somebody who knows C++ intricacies well provide an example?
Either a newly written example or a link to one. Preferably to that answer I seem to have seen.

Admittedly, this question is of value in educational settings, as a warning tale of C++ syntactic ambiguities, or when writing a parser for C++, not directly related to a problem encountered in actual software development. But if it makes you believe it doesn't belong here and should be downvoted or deleted, please instead move it to e.g. Programming Language Design and Implementation Beta Stack Exchange site, where it may be more appropriate. I think it should stay, though, as it's about something that was already written at SO and was a very popular, well received answer.

Iis this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132

There is no way to write a template such that the same * token has different meaning. The q&a linked by kakkoko is about why we sometimes need to disambiuate (not about enabling both at the same time, rather the opposite)

or I misunderstand the question :D

Dupe: Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords? .

Rather than asking to get pointed to the answer, ask the question. The thing about why we must use typename is very much related, but "is there an instance where * can have different meaning in two instantiations of a template?" is a different distinct question. The proposed duplicate, naturally, does not address this question, because it is only about the situation where we deliberately (need to) do something to prevent that ambiguity. Others may disagree, my pov is that.

I am not even trying to insist that my answer would be a good one. It is merely stating the obvious and I am looking forward to someone more knowledgable than me to give a definite answer (hopefully after the question has been improved, because It'd be a pity if it was closed)

Your recollection is incorrect - a valid expression using a * has either two operands (such as a multiplication of the form a * b) or one (such as an expression *p) or is a diagnosable error.   If one could create an expression in which usage of * was ambiguous, the required outcome is a diagnosable error.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai, what improvement could you suggest?

@Peter, as I wrote in the question, it's a multiplication expression or likely a declaration of a pointer type variable, so that bypasses your trilemma.

what I wrote. Ask the quesiton. Do not ask where to find the answer.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai, following your suggestion, my edit has the following summary: "make the question firstmost about any example of the ambiguity, only then state preference for a link to the mentioned one". As the question had been closed in the meantime, I also checked the field indicating that the edit removes the reason for closing and it should be considered for reopening, which seems to be what both of us and wohlstad hope for.

@ByteEater  A declaration of a pointer is not an expression and rules for declarations are different from rules for expressions.    And it is not possible to construct something that is syntactically both at the same time.

Sure there is. In a * b; you don't know without context if it's a statement that just contains an expression or a declaration of b of type a*. And it may be, especially if there's a qualified name instead of plain a, that in different instances of the containing template the answer is different.

An expression a * b will always have context (such as, if a and b are variables, their types) so the meaning is unambiguous.    Your problem is that you are assuming that variable declarations (or definitions) and expressions are interchangeable, when they are not  (they may syntactically look similar, but their meanings are completely different)

@Peter, you seem to ignore the fact that it's in a template. So the context may be different in each instance.

Related feature, named Universal Template Parameters, is proposed for a future version of C++ in the papers P1985 and P2989.

@ByteEater    No, I'm not.   There are contexts in template metaprogramming where a developer might intend to declare (or use) a type, but which (according to rules of the language) actually declares (or uses) a variable.   The typename keyword is used in those cases to adamantly inform the compiler "this is a type not a variable".   But that is not an example of what you claim.

As I wrote in a comment under @463035818_is_not_an_ai's answer (now deleted, probably due to having been harassed there by Alex), in recent versions (C++20 and C++23, and even more planned) the typename keyword is optional in more and more contexts in which only a type can appear. If I were to attempt finding an example, I'd try to leverage some of those relaxations.

Recently it has become impossible to get answers to questions that require substantial addition to (or useful clarification of) other answers that exists already. Either that or one has to be prepared to enter a fight. I see the use of closing as dupe, but I also see the damage that overusing this feature does
